# Can a Galaxy-class saucer section join onto a Nebula-class ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Can a Galaxy-class's saucer section join onto a Nebula-class vessel?

I can’t find the answer anywhere but they both *seem* identical.

Comment: Due to customizations in the energy and computer systems I doubt you could even interchange galaxy class saucers

Comment: Galaxy class can interchange saucers. In the novel Rogue Saucer, the Enterprise tests out a new experimental saucer whilst its own is under repair.

Comment: If the saucer of one ship...is attached to the propulsion section of another ship...which ship is which? Hmmmm?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - It's the Stardrive section that gives the ship its identity. In Rogue Saucer, they don't change the name of the ship when they swap out the saucer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In theory, one could probably be made to fit the other. The saucers are of a *very similar* shape and size. In practice, however, the way that they're joined is very different. The link between the saucer on the Nebula class is almost 50 metres longer.

[image]

<sub><sup>Image Courtesy of John Eaves</sup></sub>

[As noted by Rick Sternbach](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/nebula.htm), the similarity didn't go unnoticed by the producers.

> *The Nebula is sometimes thought to be smaller than the Galaxy class.
> At least this was the original intention by the designers. Rick
> Sternbach writes at TrekBBS: **"The Nebula class was supposed to be
> smaller than the Galaxy class, IIRC; the saucer shape is similar, but
> the bridge module is larger in proportion to the saucer size, as are
> the windows. The fact that the Nebula saucer looks like a Galaxy
> saucer (shape, colors, various design elements) doesn't exactly help
> the situation, but there it is."***
>
> <sub><sup>[Nebula Class Observations](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/nebula.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice answer! Regarding the similarity in appearance as far as saucer, deflector, and nacelles go, my understanding was that they were both made at the same shipyard - Utopia Planitia, Mars. This suggests a lot of common design, possibly by the same engineering team, but not necessarily cross-compatibility on that scale.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 - Indeed. And out-of-universe, the Nebula-class was made by [kitbashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitbashing) several Enterprise-D models.